# How can I override or disable the default ListView key behavior in Scala/Swing?

Tags: swing, scala

I want to display a ListView and allow users to quickly select multiple rows from it using the keyboard and unmodified keys.  Scala (or Java) uses any keys typed to select a row if it matches the first character and removes all other previously selected rows from the selection.  I want it to add to the selection instead.

Here's one of the things I've tried where lv is previously defined as a ListView, labels is an IndexedSeq[Char] that maps characters to a row number:

```
lv.reactions += {
  case e: KeyTyped if e.modifiers == 0 => {
    val pos = labels.indexOf(e.char)
    if (pos >= 0 && pos < lv.listData.items.size) {
      e.consume()
      if (lv.selection.indices.contains(pos)) {
        lv.selection.indices -= pos
      } else {
        lv.selection.indices += pos
      }
      // Need some kind of notification here to update the display
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: I thought putting the `e.consume()` right after the first `if` statement answered my original question but further testing shows that isn't the case.  Something is still changing the selection after my call. 
 If I type them fast, it doesn't happen.  So, the question is, how do I change the selection list in my program.  it looks like I need something to inform something that the selection list has changed.  If I type them very fast, it shows them selected, but if I type slowly, only the last one I type is selected.  `lv.repaint()` doesn't do anything.

I have also tried `lv.peer.setSelectionIndices(newSel.toArray)` where `newSel` is the result of adding or dropping element `pos` to/from `lv.selection.indices` with no change in behavior.

I have also tried

```
val r = new Range(0, lv.listData.indices.size, 1)
lv.publish(new ListSelectionChanged(lv, r, false))
```

where the comment in my code is.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

The "solution" was to convert the project to scalaFX where ListView does not have that behavior. The conversion wasn't very difficult.